# Robotframework: Importing other modules from python Keyword

Tags: python, import, robotframework, keyword

I have automated tests running with Robotframework(MyRobotTestCase.robot).
These Testcases calls custom libraries ( for example myCustLib.py).

These python custom python libs import additional python libs ( not written by myself).
For example here somelib.

```
myCustLib.py:
import somelib

class myCustLib:
    def f1(self):
        somelib.fx()
        pass
```

Setup:

- Basic Python installation on Windows
- Virtual enviroment created an activated

  - inside Virtual Env robot framework and somelib installed with
    python -m pip install robot
    python -m pip install somelib

Now my Problem:
If I test my myCustLib.py inside python everything is ok.

If I try ro run MyTestCase.robot with myCustLib.py as Library I received
an import error.
It looks that it is impossible to import somelib from inside myCustLib.py

If I delete the import of somelib inside myCustLib.py the Testcase works without
any Problems.

So do I have to set an addtional PythonPath inside the virtual enviroment?
I thougt that if I have a venv and robot runs inside the activated venv everything is setup correctly.

When I installed everything in the main Python enviroment ( robot and somelib)
it works. But that's not the way how it should work.

From my view it must be the virtual env and robot.
How can I tell robot to find somelib in the virtual env?

I put my additonal libs in the virtual env and expected that robot can see them

Comment: Are you sure you are running the venv `robot`? Like `<path to venv>/bin/robot` or `python -m robot` ? Do you have an helper script that places venv first in PATH?

Comment: yes I have a venv activated. inside this venv ist robot installed. Ich check this with python - m pip list. here is also see that some lib, see above, is installed in the venv. no I just use the activate script for the venv. I think that is done from the activate script

Comment: I still think you are running a different `robot`. Just compare before and after activation of venv with the command: `python -m robot --version`  (I even suggest you install in venv a different version of `robot`, like 6.0.2).

Comment: hi, ok solved the problem. it is a little bit strange. on some reason I opened the robot file with notepad ++ and saw that there is special char in the library statement. this char I did not see inside visual studio code. I then delete the char and everything works. don't know where this char comes from. but now everything runs as expected

Comment: did I need to close this question somehow?

Comment: Maybe you should have posted your ` I received an import error.` it should have give us an hint of the problem. The best you can do is to write an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned in my comment the behaviour was caused by a control character inside the robot file. I could not see this in visual studio code.
after deleting this everything works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).